# Recursive function not outputting intended value

Tags: python-2.7, function, recursion, speech-recognition

I' m happy trouble understanding why the function below seems to be outputting `None` instead of `1` if the function doesn't have a vakud output on its first run through.

```
import win32com.client
BING_KEY = "XXXXXXXX"
import speech_recognition as sr
import win32com.client as wincl

s = sr.Recognizer()

def hey_pc():
    print(" Hey PC = Command")
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
          audio = s.listen(source)
          try:
               x= (s.recognize_bing(audio, key=BING_KEY))
               if x in ['hey PC']:
                return 1
               else: hey_pc()
          except:
               print('Try again')
               hey_pc()




t = hey_pc()
print t
```

if the function outputs on its first run, I get the following output:

`Hey PC == Command
1`

But if it invokes its recursive property, I get a final output of `None`

```
 Hey PC == Command
 Hey PC == Command
 Hey PC == Command
 Hey PC == Command
None
```

or this

```
 Hey PC == Command
 Try again
 Hey PC == Command
 Hey PC == Command
 None
```

I don't understand why I"m getting "None."

EDIT:

I've changed the second part of the code to this and played around more but still have the same problem:

```
t =hey_pc()

if t == 1:

        speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
        speak.Speak("This is the pc voice speaking")
        import automation
        automation.Apply_Command()
else:
        hey_pc()
```

If my voice is recognized on its first attempt, the code under `if t==1` is ran and there no problems, however if my voice is not recognized on its first attempt and recurvise portion of the code is activated, once my voice  finally gets recognized, the program just ends (meaning the Python command prompt `>>>` pops up again). So I'm assuming it's the null value that's being passed on.

Still stumped. :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, specifically, but it's generally because "if x in ['hey PC']" is NEVER true. The only condition where a number is returned (and thus setting a value) is your if statement. So, most likely, that if statement is never entered into.

Comment: However, I get an output of 1 if the function runs smoothly (without calling the recursion portion of the function). If the I run the above function, manage to get an output without evoking `Try Again` or `Hey PC` output more than once, (which would indicate that the recursion portion the function is being activiated ), I"m able to get an output of 1. 
Hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to say.